# Add of a latitude and longitude fields to a Odoo view

Tags: xml, odoo

I want to modify the current view of the sales/after sales/reclamation views in Odoo 8 by adding 2 char fields: Latitude and longitude to locate the partner (client) in an after sales process, how can I do this please ?

Comment: I think there is a module to do that and it shows you the coordinates  in the map as well. I don't know right now the name. You can look for it in [Odoo Apps](https://www.odoo.com/apps) or in the OCA repository in Git Hub

Answer (score 1):

There is already website_google_map module available in community . in that u can enter Latitude and longitude to Partner form and hit button on Geo Localization button and get map.

Answer (score 0):

```
class inherit_res_partner(models.Model):

     _inherit='res.partner'
     latitude=fields.Char('Latitude')
     longitude=fields.Char('Longitude')
```

Comment: Why do you suggest to use Char? Why not Float?

Answer (score 0):

There is a module `base_geolocalize` that adds both fields to the `res_partner` view in the Geo Localization tab. You can make related fields to show them wherever you want.

You can install this module as well, to show the coordinates in Google Maps: [partner_external_maps](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/partner_external_maps/)

> If the module base_geolocalize from the official addons is installed
>   on the system, it will use the latitude and longitude to localize the
>   partner (instead of the address) if this information is present on the
>   partner.